# Combinatorial proof for the following fact: $\binom{2n}{n+1}+2\binom{2n}{n}+\binom{2n}{n-1}=\binom{2n+2}{n+1}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> $$\binom{2n}{n+1}+2\binom{2n}{n}+\binom{2n}{n-1}=\binom{2n+2}{n+1}$$
>   Hint: From 2n + 2 players, consider 2 players (call them A, B) separately.

I found this question in my textbook with no context about the players.

Comment: i didnt know how to type it and i found this question in my textbook just like this with no context

Comment: There are too many nannies who prefer to criticize rather than help.  Here is the expression. Add in the text.   $\binom{2n}{n+1}+2\binom{2n}{n}+\binom{2n}{n-1}=\binom{2n+2}{n+1}$.  Combinatorial proof.

Comment: Following the hint, the right hand side means number of the ways to choose $n+1$ players among $2n+2$ players. How can you interpret the left hand side, by "considering 2 players A and B separately"?

Comment: @DimaSmith78 We understand there is no further context in the textbook. But what is the context of your involvement with the problem -- what have you tried, what are your thoughts, where are you stuck?

Comment: @CaveJohnson i dont really understand how to work with the middle term on the left side

Comment: @Y.Forman as i mentioned in my comment, i dont know how to involve the "2" in the middle term on the left side

Comment: Would it be clearer for you, if I write the left hand side as $\binom20\binom{2n}{n+1}+\binom21\binom{2n}{n}+\binom22\binom{2n}{n-1}$? Note how the "$2$" players we separated appear in this formula.

Comment: Consider selections which include neither $A$ nor $B$, exactly one of them, or both $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've clarified that your question is about the $2\binom{2n}n$ term, I'll relate specifically to that. My advice: don't worry too much about it. If it helps consider it as two separate $\binom{2n}n$ terms added together. These terms should arise organically from your combinatorial interpretation of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

${\mathrm C}^{2n+2}_{n+1}$ counts how to select $n+1$ players from $2n+2$ players (where the hint suggests naming the plus two players A and B).

What then do the three terms $1{\mathrm C}^{2n}_{n+1},2{\mathrm C}^{2n}_{n},$ and $1{\mathrm C}^{2n}_{n-1}$ each count?   How do $1,2,1$ relate to selection of players?   What might the hint about the two named players have to do with it?